# server gets down while copying data from csv to cassandra

Tags: csv, cassandra, copy

I want to copy data from csv file (more than 10 million records and file size is 4 gb) to cassandra. for that I have used COPY command as below,

```
COPY table_name (list_of_columns) FROM 'FilePath' WITH HEADER = true;
```

It is loading data to table, but after loading some data (400-500k records) the server gets down. This might be because for huge file. What could be the issue?

Also how can I copy the remaining data only instead of truncating the existing data and start from the beginning?

Comment: Which cassandra and cqlsh version are you using ?

Comment: Did you check the `system.log` for error log ?

Comment: Cassandra version is 3.9 and cqlsh version is 5.0.1. I have checked the system.log file but could not able to get/understand anything except there is one log which is continuously coming is that 'Batch for [keyspacename.tablename] is of size 11.116KiB, exceeding specified threshold of 5.000KiB by 6.116KiB.'.

Comment: And did you see any error on the dead node ? If yes, edit your question and add the full error log

Comment: The error says the batch size exceed, so try to add batch limit with `copy` command. Try this `COPY table_name (list_of_columns) FROM 'FilePath' WITH HEADER = true AND MINBATCHSIZE = 2 AND MAXBATCHSIZE = 5;`

Comment: I checked the cassandra.yaml file. it has following properties: batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5 and batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50 so I think it was just a warning as batch size exceeds than 5kb. and It should give error after exceeding 50 kb. One more thing I am trying to load 4 gb of csv file while I am not having that much free ram to process. If this is the cause then what is feasible way to load this file. I dont want to split file in number of small sub files and then load it. I want to achieve it using that 4 gb file only.

Comment: You can increase the `batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb`, default value is 50, but it's not recommended to increase